How to fix Duplicate class com.google.firebase.Timestamp
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.Timestamp found in modules jetified-firebase-common-21.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:21.0.0) and jetified-firebase-firestore-24.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0)

Duplicate class com.google.firebase.Timestamp found in modules jetified-firebase-common-21.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:21.0.0) and
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.Timestamp found in modules jetified-firebase-common-21.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:21.0.0) and jetified-firebase-firestore-24.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0)

add = > include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')
in settings.gradle  work for me

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project: Go to Build > Clean Project then Build > Rebuild Project

Google needs to create a new IDE that actually works, every time you have to change anything involving Gradle in Android Studio it blows up the entire project and you have to spend weeks pulling your hair out trying to figure it out I'm so sick of this.....

I have same issue occurred in my react native firebase project. I have fixed the issue by changing in android/app/build.gradle file.
Note : versions for Firebase SDKs are chosen automatically by the BoM, so just remove or modify if any firebase dependency ends with specific version or :+
In my case, I am not using firebase analytics in my app but it still implemented in gradle file. So, I have comment 1 firebase dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:+ and my issue resolved.
Don't forget to remove node_modules and clean Android build folder before rebuild. Thanks .

add = >
include ':@react-native-firebase_app' 
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, 
'../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android') 

in settings.gradle dont work for me. Did you do anything different besides that?
my firebase versions:
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "17.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "17.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "17.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "17.5.0",

The error:
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.firebase.Timestamp found in modules jetified-firebase-common-21.0.0-runtime
> (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:21.0.0) and
> jetified-firebase-firestore-24.10.3-runtime
> (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.10.3)


add this => in app/ build.gradle
dependencies {
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_app")

Disable  line  =>  // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'.
}
and Try cleaning and rebuilding the project: Go to Build > Clean Project then Build > Rebuild Project

that didn't work. I still get the error:

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.Timestamp found in modules jetified-firebase-common-21.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:21.0.0) and jetified-firebase-firestore-24.4.5-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.5)


We encountered the same issue, on the Unity platform.
As far as I understand, the issue originates in their implementation - Google has released an update on May 2nd, which has this class as part of the new common-21.0.0 version, and that breaks users of Firestore package.
What we did, is to make sure we do not download common-21.0.0. We edited the gradle build file to download common-20.4.2 which was the last version we knew that works.
Like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78444928/24949559 answer, the problem is usage of "+" or a non-specific version.
I do think that still Google should resolve it, and I opened a ticket for them and I am in contact with them at the moment.

In my case I had to comment out this line in /android/build.gradle:
//firebaseMessagingVersion = "+"

So the complete file looks like this:
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = '+'
        //firebaseMessagingVersion = '+'
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlinVersion = "1.7.21"
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        ffmpegKitPackage = "min-gpl"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath("com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:7.+")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:3.7.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


update:
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:25.0.0")


This doesn't appear to be an answer. If it is could you please re-phrase it?

Jose Cruz solution works for my scene.
My former gradle.app dependecies is like:
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")   

I change it to:
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:25.0.0")      

It works
